# How to creath xpath using appium uiautomatorviewer in android?

Tags: android, mobile, xpath, automation, appium

How to create XPath using UI automator viewer. Currently I am testing mobile web applications. Here I need to identify object properties, i have tried to use properties identified by firebug and relative XPath but it could not workout.
Could you please guide me how to create XPath using appium UI automator viewer in android ?

I am using android in windows machine. I would like to get ID, name and XPath of the objects in mobile web browser.

[image]

Setup below:

```
public void Appium() throws MalformedURLException{

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","097f2163010ad15f");

            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS");

            capabilities.setCapability("app", "chrome");
           driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: Click on the check box with your mouse pinter, you will get that ID, the use that ID, To find Xpath you will need appium inspector and appium set up on MAC

Comment: I have appium inspector,but i am using android with windows machine.Can i create xpath using appium inspector in windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

In Appium framework XPath syntax is a bit different from the one used in Web as @Gaurav mentions.

If you would print the XML page source it would be a bit more easier for you to understand the structure. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">
    <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1776]" resource-id="" instance="0">
        <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1776]" resource-id="" instance="0">
            <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,75][1080,1776]" resource-id="" instance="1">
                <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,75][1080,1776]" resource-id="com.test:id/action_bar_root" instance="2">
                    <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,75][1080,1776]" resource-id="android:id/content" instance="3">
                        <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,75][1080,1776]" resource-id="" instance="1"/>
                    </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                </android.widget.FrameLayout>
            </android.widget.FrameLayout>
        </android.widget.LinearLayout>
    </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

So in **Your** case to find element the code would be following:
`driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath("//android.widget.CheckBox[@index='1']"))`

@Gaurav's example also is logically correct but the star should not be there like this:
`driver.findElementsByXPath("//[@class='android.widget.CheckBox' and @index='1']");`

Comment: No.It didn't work.Getting following error:    
  FAILED: testCal
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.12 seconds

Comment: Ofcourse, because I see you are using Chrome driver. You must use AndroidDriver. :)
Could you provide your driver setup?

Comment: Thank you.Updated my setup in the code.Please have a look on my original question.

Comment: Why are you using Web driver, if you are testing Application? Does not make sense to me. Use an AndroidDriver!
And parameter "app" takes path to the `.apk` file, not just name.
More info: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Comment: I m testing my application in android chrome browser.Its web application,so no '.apk' file available.Also when I use **driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(“http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub”), capabilities);** I am getting error as _The constructor AndroidDriver() is undefined_

Comment: Then I still do not understand your setup. In your example you show that you are trying to find XPath for Android application, but now you say you do not - you are testing Mobile web. There is a big difference. Please adjust you question content accordingly.
P.S. I am working with Appium for iOS and Android and everything is fine on multiple environments and devices parallel.

Comment: updated the screen shot.Actually our app available in native and web.So i thought both will be same xpath. Sorry for the confusion.Added my web app screenshot,in that I am trying identify the "No" option.Thanks for ur support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create xpath in your window above, it would be like this:

```
driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@content-desc='No' and @index='16']");
```

Just keep changing the parameters as per your need.

Comment: No Gaurav.It didn't work out.Still facing the issue.I am using android web application in appium(chrome browser).Following is my error.                          FAILED: testCal
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.05 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.h